# Popups no longer function after filtering markers in mapbox

Tags: javascript, filter, popup, mapbox

I have set up features from an external geoJson file in Mapbox and bound popups to these features following the example at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/custom-popup/

```
var myLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer(bldgData).addTo(map);

myLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {

    // set up popup for each marker
    var content = "";
    var props = layer.feature.properties;
    var imagePart = "<img class='popupPic' src='images/thumbnails/" + props.filename + "' ></img>";
    var infoPart = "<h3 class='popupInfo'>" + props.bldgName + "</h3><p>" +
        props.architect + "<br />" + props.year + "</p>";
    content = imagePart + infoPart;

    layer.bindPopup(content, {closeButton: false});
});
```

The popups are set up to display on mouseover...

```
myLayer.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    e.layer.closePopup();
    e.layer.openPopup();
});

myLayer.on('mouseout', function(e) {
    e.layer.closePopup();
});
```

I have also set up filtering to display selected features following the example at https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-markers/

```
function chooseBldg(){
    var bldgs = document.getElementById("buildingTypeMenu").value;

    if(bldgs == "all") {
        myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {return true;});

    }
    else {
        myLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
            return f.properties['buildingType'] === bldgs;
        }); 
    }
}
```

The popups display correctly when I first display the page, and the filters correctly select the subset of markers to display, but after the filter has been triggered the popups no longer display on mouseover.  Do I need to rebind the popups (by explicitly triggering the eachLayer function or something) after the filter has been done?

Answer (score 0):

Rebind popups solved this problem for me.

Comment: Well, it worked in the sense that the popups no longer disappear, but each popup now shows only the last record in the geojson.  Could you share the code for how you solved the probelm?

Comment: Wrap the bindPopup inside a layer.foreach() right after setting the filter function....

myLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
     var content = "Info goes here";
     layer.bindPopup(content, {closeButton: false});
});