# Rebind Mapbox popups after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, leaflet, mapbox

I've built a Mapbox map that has a fairly involved custom popup structure, including photos and formatting. I'm using a .csv file and omnivore to feed my data, and creating the popup .on ready. I've also got a search box that searches the data using jQuery.

Independently, each one works. The popups load fine, and the search is working. But after filtering using the search thing, I lose the popups.

I've looked at this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723547/popups-no-longer-function-after-filtering-markers-in-mapbox) but nothing suggested seems to be working. I think this has to do with my popup variable being contained inside of the .on ready function. Is there something I'm missing here? Do I need to restructure how the popups are created?

Here's my code:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

jQuery('#search').keyup(search);
```

Load data, format popups:

```
var csvLayer = omnivore.csv('Stats.csv', null, L.mapbox.featureLayer())
    .on('ready', function() {

        map.fitBounds(csvLayer.getBounds(), {paddingTopLeft: [0,25]});

 function updownFormat(updown, change){
            if (updown === '&#8212;') {
                return "No change ";
            } else if (updown === "N/A") {
                return "New store - no data ";
            } else if (updown === '&#9650;') {
                return '<span class="upPercent">' + updown + "</span> " + change;
            } else {
                return '<span class="downPercent">' + updown + "</span> " + change;
            }
        };

        csvLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
            var prop = layer.feature.properties
            var popup = '<div class="popup"><h3>'+ prop.storename +'<\/h3>' +
            '<h4>'+ prop.town +'</h4>' +
            '<p><b>Rank:</b> #'+ prop.rank +' (of 80 stores) <br>' +
            '<b>Sales: </b>' + prop.money14 +' (2014)<br>' + 
            '<b>Growth: </b>' + updownFormat(prop.updown, prop.change) + ' (from 2013)</p>' +
            '<h5>Best selling bottles (2014)</h5>' + 
            '<img src="'+ prop.pop1img +'" class="liquorimg">' +
            '<ol><li><b>'+prop.pop1+'</b></li><li>'+prop.pop2+'</li><li>'+prop.pop3+'</li><li>'+prop.pop4+'</li><li>'+prop.pop5+'</li></ol></div>';
            layer.bindPopup(popup);

        });


    })
    .addTo(map);
```

The search function:

```
function search() {
    // get the value of the search input field
    var searchString = jQuery('#search').val().toLowerCase();

    csvLayer.setFilter(showStoreTown);

    function showStoreTown(feature) {
        return feature.properties.storetown
            .toLowerCase()
            .indexOf(searchString) !== -1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, thanks to Twitter! Setting map bounds on "ready" and setting the popup creation on "addlayer" took care of it.